# what is the purpose of -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio

Tags: java, heap-memory

Kindly tell me the purpose of those options.
After googling I think:
MinHeapFreeRatio tells "specified minimum percentage of space will be ensured to be free in heap memory after a GC"
and
MaxHeapFreeRatio tells "no more than specified percentage of space will be free in heap memory after a GC" [if there is excess free memory than the specified percentage, those memory will be returned to OS]

When i tried these options with 10 as value for both, even where there is more than 80 percentage of free heap memory, it was not released back to OS.

Details:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (1.5.0_15-b04, mixed mode) 
ParallelGC (otherwise known as throughput collector which is the default collector in server class VM) 
i specified -Xms50M and -Xmx1000M as jvm arguments 
OS: windows 7 professional (8 GB memory 64 bit OS)

Note: i just tried with SerialGC too, those min and max heap free ratio options were ignored.

Comment: I guess it's setting a range of percentage, right? should not both set to 10, but setting to values like: `MinHeapFreeRatio=10` and `MaxHeapFreeRatio=90`, hope I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 15):

The best explanation of the parameters -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio parameters are available in the oracle garbage collector documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/factors-affecting-garbage-collection-performance.htm

```
-XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=40
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
```

With these options, if the percent of free space in a generation falls below 40%, then the generation expands to maintain 40% free space, up to the maximum allowed size of the generation. Similarly, if the free space exceeds 70%, then the generation contracts so that only 70% of the space is free, subject to the minimum size of the generation.

I combine it with the G1GC in this way:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=2 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=10
```

With this result:

[image: Heap size over time with the explained parammeters]

Comment: Hi Martin, what program are you using on the screenshot? I'm begining with this deep world of JVM and that kind of tool looks very useful. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JaiMartz, you have a lot of programs to do it: java mission control, Eclipse Memory Analyzer or VisualVM (used for this screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

Java **very rarely** releases memory back to the OS.

Generally speaking, applications use more memory over time rather than less. Are you sure you memory is so limited that you need this?  Are you sure you are checking the resident memory not the virtual memory size which will be about 1.2 GB in your case all the time.

Comment: yes peter i checked the memory usage using VisualVM.
And i think ParallelGC will ignore those options, it just dynamically resizes young and old generations based on "pause time" and "throughput" goals.
https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/it_s_not_magic

Comment: @PraveenKumar, can you confirm if `MinHeapRatio` and `MaxHeapRatio` are ignored by parallel collector?