# Trying to see the GC behaviors, and How could I get the heap size and used memory usage on MAC pro?

Tags: garbage-collection

I am adding JVM args by using -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio to see the GC behavior changes. I got some explanations here ([what is the purpose of -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058250/what-is-the-purpose-of-xxminheapfreeratio-and-xxmaxheapfreeratio))
The question is how could I get the memory usage picture in the answer. I wanna make sure the modifications I made can really change the GC behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It is a tool called [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)

There are some other alternatives such us [JConsole](https://openjdk.org/tools/svc/jconsole/) or [Java Mission Control](https://jdk.java.net/jmc/8/)